# how to disable NumericUpDownExtender after first click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using NumericUpDownExtender inside updatepanel which is inside repeater displays comments on article. I use NumericUpDownExtender as thumbs up/down and I need to disable it after first click so that no one can rate the comment more than once. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is up to date, so I found a solution.

My problem was to disable the NumericUpDownExtender when a checkbox is checked for 'All Numbers'. It could be used for null too, if nullable int. I could disable the textbox, but the user was able to increment or decrement the value through the NumericUpDownExtender.

I think there is no problem to catch the specified event...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbNumber" runat="server" />
<cc1:NumericUpDownExtender ID="nudNumber" runat="server"
    Minimum="1" TargetControlID="tbNumber" Width="70" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbAllNumber" runat="server" Text="All Numbers" 
    OnChange="javascript:handleNumber();"/>
```

...and call a javascript function like this, which should be the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleNumber() {
        var numId = "<%= tbNumber.ClientID %>";
        var nudId = "<%= nudNumber.ClientID %>";
        if ($get("<%= cbAllNumber.ClientID %>").checked) {
            $get(numId).disabled = true;
            $find(nudId)._bUp.disabled = true;
            $find(nudId)._bDown.disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            $get(numId).disabled = false;
            $find(nudId)._bUp.disabled = false;
            $find(nudId)._bDown.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

We need to $find the NumericUpDownExtender through the BehaviorID. If this is not set, this is your ID, respectively your ClientID, like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The NumericUpDownExtender has three controls that need to be disabled, referenced by TargetControlID, TargetButtonDownID and TargetButtonUpID. If you disable these three controls on the first callback, this should do it.

Comment: will you explain how? because I just want to disable it on the rated comment while he can rate other comment as well.